# Issue with creating a custom view within a scrollview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am facing problem in creating a custom view within a `scrollview` in `iOS`. Only one image is added to the screen, which is the last map and only one title is added. The rest do not appear. I need to have 4 images and 4 text.

My custom class is called `mapview`.

**My custom view should look like this:**

[image]

This is the how scrollview is set in **ViewController.m**

```
-(void)initialiseScreen
{

    NSArray *MapGalleryArray = [[Singleton sharedManager] getMapGalleryItems];
    int yOffset = 0;
    for (int counter=0; counter < [MapGalleryArray count]; counter++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.JPG",[[MapGalleryArray objectAtIndex:counter] objectForKey:@"Image"]];
        UIImage *MapImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        NSString *titletext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[MapGalleryArray objectAtIndex:counter] objectForKey:@"Title"]];

        MapView *map = [[MapView alloc] initWithImage:MapImage label:titletext];
        [MapScrollView addSubview:map];

        yOffset +=MapScrollView.frame.size.height/MapGalleryArray count];
    }
    [MapScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(MapScrollView.frame.size.width, yOffset)];
}
```

**MapView.h**

```
  @interface MapView : UIView
    {
        UIButton    *mapViewButton;
        UILabel     *titeLabel;
    }

    @property(nonatomic,retain)     UIButton        *mapViewButton;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)     UILabel         *titleLabel;

    -(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image label:(NSString*)text;
```

**MapView.m**

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image label:(NSString*)text
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2);

        mapViewButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
        [mapViewButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mapViewButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [mapViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ImageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, mapViewButton.frame.size.width+5, mapViewButton.frame.size.height)];
        [titleLabel setText:text];

        [self addSubview:mapViewButton];
        [self addSubview:titleLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Need some guidance on this, where I am doing the mistake. 
Sorry as this is my first time creating a custom view.
Welcome to any suggestions as well.

Comment: you want to add images horizantally or vertically?

Comment: i want to add image vertically..

Comment: Please print the value of yOffset and MapScrollView.frame.size.height in log. it may help you to solve this issue. Best luck!!

Comment: any help guys? besides @ShahPaneri's help

Comment: i changed the height to this: yOffset +=MapScrollView.frame.size.height/MapGalleryArray count]; and it is still not working

Comment: You are not setting the frame of your mapView. That's the problem

Comment: where you are passing frame for map?

Comment: You can display image and title dynamically by adding into scroll view instead taking another view. I have done like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding MapView at same possion on scroll view thats why you are able to see only last view added.increase the x/y of MapView and set the new contentSize for ur scrollView.  try following.

```
for (int counter=0; counter < [MapGalleryArray count]; counter++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.JPG",[[MapGalleryArray objectAtIndex:counter] objectForKey:@"Image"]];
        UIImage *MapImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        NSString *titletext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[MapGalleryArray objectAtIndex:counter] objectForKey:@"Title"]];

        //horizontal scroll view    
        MapView *map = [[MapView alloc] initWithImage:MapImage label:titletext];
        float width = map.frame.size.width;    
         [map setFrame:CGRectmake((width*counter)+5, //x ,
             map.frame.origin.y, //y
             map.frame.size.width, //width
            map.frame.size.height)]; //height

        [MapScrollView addSubview:map];

   MapScrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake((width+5)*10,
                                          MapScrollView.frame.size.height
               );
        yOffset +=MapScrollView.frame.size.height;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the problem with the frame setting to the MapView.m

Try with this code...

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)initialiseScreen
{

    NSArray *MapGalleryArray = [[Singleton sharedManager] getMapGalleryItems];
    int yOffset = 0;
    int xOffset = 0;
    for (int counter=0; counter < [MapGalleryArray count]; counter++)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.JPG",[[MapGalleryArray objectAtIndex:counter] objectForKey:@"Image"]];
        UIImage *MapImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

        NSString *titletext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[MapGalleryArray objectAtIndex:counter] objectForKey:@"Title"]];
        CGPoint position = CGPointMake(xOffset, yOffset);
        MapView *map = [[MapView alloc] initWithImage:MapImage label:titletext andPoint:position];
        [MapScrollView addSubview:map];

        yOffset +=MapScrollView.frame.size.height/[MapGalleryArray count];
    }
    [MapScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(MapScrollView.frame.size.width, yOffset)];
}
```

**MapView.h**

```
@interface MapView : UIView
    {
        UIButton    *mapViewButton;
        UILabel     *titeLabel;
    }

    @property(nonatomic,retain)     UIButton        *mapViewButton;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)     UILabel         *titleLabel;

    -(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image label:(NSString*)text andPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

**MapView.m**

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image label:(NSString*)text andPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2);

        mapViewButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
        [mapViewButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mapViewButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [mapViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ImageButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, mapViewButton.frame.size.width+5, mapViewButton.frame.size.height)];
        [titleLabel setText:text];

        [self addSubview:mapViewButton];
        [self addSubview:titleLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This will solve your problem....